# UIActionSheet release after dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I am using `UIActionSheet` in my project:

```
self.actionSheet = [[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil] autorelease];
```

This is the Object:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActionSheet *actionSheet;
```

And after the `UIActionSheet` is dismissed I want to release it and make it `nil` with this code:

```
[self.actionSheet release];
self.actionSheet = nil;
```

But when I do it the app crashes, any idea why it happens?

Comment: You must use ARC enabled code... autorelease is history.

Comment: @iAnurag I had not realized that Apple had removed MRC from the compiler. Why not jump straight to swift? Maybe objective-c is history!

Comment: @iAnurag No, you do not have to use ARC.

Comment: Are you sure you need to keep the `UIActionSheet` instance in a property? Usually you don't have save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually calling `release` is the problem. When using the synthesized setter of a property, it properly releases the previous object.

You should either change your code to:

```
self.actionSheet = nil;
```

or, if you prefer to manually release, set the underlying instance variable to `nil`, like so:

```
[self.actionSheet release];
_actionSheet = nil;
```

As suggested in the comments, you should migrate your code to ARC. If you cannot migrate all of the code, you can still migrate most of it and only keep the "problematic" code in MRC.